How do I resolve this Cloudformation WAF deployment error
I am trying to deploy a WAF via Cloudformation and I am getting the following error:
"Resource handler returned message: "AWS WAF couldn?t perform the operation because some resource in your request is a duplicate of an existing one. (Service: Wafv2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 8debed46-5b0b-4ebe-89f2-fb3230607146)" (RequestToken: b8554049-ad37-fb63-a70a-17306b4aea54, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)"
I can't figure out which resource is apparently being duplicated in the stack though...any help would be appreciated...
---
Metadata:
  TemplateId: "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:200053671793:generatedTemplate/5fed0534-2467-43ec-bf2d-d6cdbcba977c"
Resources:
  WAFv2WebACL00REGIONAL003mMpL:
    UpdateReplacePolicy: "Retain"
    Type: "AWS::WAFv2::WebACL"
    DeletionPolicy: "Retain"
    Properties:
      Description: "webacl"
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {}
      Scope: "REGIONAL"
      Rules:
      - Action:
          Allow: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "NoUserAgent-api-acii"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 0
        Statement:
          ByteMatchStatement:
            TextTransformations:
            - Type: "NONE"
              Priority: 0
            PositionalConstraint: "CONTAINS"
            SearchString: "/api/acii/"
            FieldToMatch:
              UriPath: {}
        Name: "NoUserAgent-api-acii"
      - OverrideAction:
          None: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 1
        Statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            ManagedRuleGroupConfigs: []
            VendorName: "AWS"
            RuleActionOverrides: []
            ExcludedRules: []
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
        Name: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
      - OverrideAction:
          None: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 2
        Statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            ManagedRuleGroupConfigs: []
            VendorName: "AWS"
            RuleActionOverrides: []
            ExcludedRules: []
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
        Name: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
      - OverrideAction:
          None: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 3
        Statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            ManagedRuleGroupConfigs: []
            VendorName: "AWS"
            RuleActionOverrides: []
            ExcludedRules: []
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"
        Name: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"
      - OverrideAction:
          Count: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 4
        Statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            ManagedRuleGroupConfigs: []
            VendorName: "AWS"
            RuleActionOverrides:
            - ActionToUse:
                Count: {}
              Name: "SizeRestrictions_BODY"
            - ActionToUse:
                Count: {}
              Name: "CrossSiteScripting_BODY"
            ExcludedRules: []
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
        Name: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
      - OverrideAction:
          None: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 5
        Statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            ManagedRuleGroupConfigs: []
            VendorName: "AWS"
            RuleActionOverrides: []
            ExcludedRules: []
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList"
        Name: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList"
      - OverrideAction:
          None: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesBotControlRuleSet"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 6
        Statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            ManagedRuleGroupConfigs:
            - AWSManagedRulesBotControlRuleSet:
                InspectionLevel: "COMMON"
            VendorName: "AWS"
            RuleActionOverrides:
            - ActionToUse:
                Allow: {}
              Name: "CategoryMonitoring"
            - ActionToUse:
                Allow: {}
              Name: "SignalNonBrowserUserAgent"
            - ActionToUse:
                Allow: {}
              Name: "CategorySocialMedia"
            - ActionToUse:
                Allow: {}
              Name: "CategoryHttpLibrary"
            ExcludedRules: []
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesBotControlRuleSet"
        Name: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesBotControlRuleSet"
      - OverrideAction:
          None: {}
        RuleLabels: []
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          MetricName: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList"
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        Priority: 7
        Statement:
          ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
            ManagedRuleGroupConfigs: []
            VendorName: "AWS"
            RuleActionOverrides: []
            ExcludedRules: []
            Name: "AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList"
        Name: "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList"
      VisibilityConfig:
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true
        MetricName: "DCProd"
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
      Name: "DCProd"
  WAFv2LoggingConfiguration00regionalwebaclDCProdb678b446ca0f49cca6990a8bf0fe1b6b00NAcLH:
    UpdateReplacePolicy: "Retain"
    Type: "AWS::WAFv2::LoggingConfiguration"
    DeletionPolicy: "Retain"
    Properties:
      RedactedFields: []
      ResourceArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - "WAFv2WebACL00REGIONAL003mMpL"
        - "Arn"
      LogDestinationConfigs:
      - "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:533267422905:log-group:aws-waf-logs-PROD"
  WAFloggroup: 
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: aws-waf-logs-PROD
      RetentionInDays: 7


Are you sure you don't have any WAF rules you've manually created previously?
